# geany does not open terminal to run my code, unless there is another terminal window is open

Tags: linux, geany

I am using `geany` version `1.36` in linux, whenever I press `f5` or click on `run icon` in toolbar, it does not open any terminal window to run my code in. but if I open another terminal window and do nothing in it, just let it be there, all of a sudden `f5` and run button work perfectly.
how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please report an issue with more details at the bug tracker https://github.com/geany/geany/issues

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Go to : Edit --> Preferences --> Tools --> Terminal :

[Refer here For more clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXgGO.png)

And replace the existing lines with any of the given texts...
(Adding Terminal path here)

- `x-terminal-emulator -e /bin/sh %c`
- `mate-terminal  "-e /bin/sh %c"`
- `x-terminal-emulator -e "/bin/sh %c"`
- `xterm -e "/bin/sh %c"`
- `xfce4-terminal -e "/bin/sh %c"`

The 1st one worked for me.

For More Information about this issue [Refer This Link](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/1369)

Comment: A nod for effort and use of formatting. You may want to avoid using heading tags in answers (e.g. `<hN>`) and instead just use **Bold** (two `**` before and after title) for section headings in your answers -- that tends to be closer to the right size (that is completely up to you, just a tip)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank You

Answer (score 0):

May you don't have the correct path for the terminal, every Linux OS comes with different terminal.

Try installing xterm:

```
sudo apt-get install xterm
```

And go to Edit>Tools>Preferences>Terminal, change the path for:

```
xterm -e "/bin/sh %c"
```